# how will an underground city state work?

Tags: environment, underground

In my upcoming book, nuclear war broke out and the survivors were forced to live underground indefinitely.

How would a subterranean city operate, especially in regards to accommodation, movement and architecture?

Will the ceiling be high enough for planes to fly? Will satellites work? Will automobiles work? I'm concerned about how the layout/map of the city will be like without giving its inhabitant the sense of claustrophobia. Cheers!

Comment: Have you read metro 2033? It's set in a similar world, but people moved underground into railway stations in Mosco.

Comment: no but i'll check it out. thanks a ton

Comment: caves of steel - asimov

Comment: You are new here! Welcome. This question/these questions are very broad--it's asking "I have an underground city. What will it be like?" too broad
There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: You have to solve the food situation.  There are various flora and fauna that live underground, but not in sufficient numbers to keep a significant number of people alive.

Comment: One thing you have to keep in mind is that radiation actually fades pretty fast. Most of it would be gone within a few days, and levels would be safe again too fast to justify building a city. Maybe cancer rates would go up, but the radiation would not be fatal in most cases. https://io9.gizmodo.com/how-to-shelter-from-fallout-after-a-nuclear-attack-on-y-1502362584 https://top.quora.com/How-long-does-nuclear-fallout-last/answer/Allen-E-Hall-2 However, most people do not know this, so your setting could work. And you could say the nukes were modified in some way to have stronger radiation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To state the obvious, your underground city will be a (natural or artificial) cave, or perhaps a complex of connected caves. It is improbable that the cave would be large enough for a plane. It may be large enough to require cars.

- It appears unlikely that cars with combustion engines would be allowed in. They use irreplaceable fuel and produce noxious exhausts. But some bunkers are [big enough for real cars](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Cheyenne_Mountain_Complex_entrance.jpg).
- You may have electric cars, either powered by batteries or with contact power. The cars could run on rails, like subway cars, or they could be something like a golf caddy. Here is a picture of an [electric train](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:15-26-56-ouv-schoenenbourg.jpg) in the [Maginot Line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maginot_Line) forts, here [rails](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Balaklava_Naval_Museum_-_arsenal.jpg) in a former Soviet bunker.

Answer (score 0):

It would most likely be a series of rooms connected by tunnels. More a REALLY big bunker then a city with buildings.